# Avoid converting sigma to final sigma solved but why does it work?

Tags: characters, greek

I was trying to prevent LaTeX from converting a sigma (σ) to the so called final sigma (ς) in an abbreviation:

> συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (σ.π.π.)

appeared as

> συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (ς.π.π.)

which is wrong in Greek.
Writing it as ({σ}.π.π.) didn't work, but following directions from
http://myria.math.aegean.gr/localguide/TeXguide/TeXguide.html#sigma-in-final-position (sorry, it's in Greek) helped.
It suggests writing the abbreviation as

> συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (σ**v**.π.π.)

Why does this work? What does this (Latin character) v change?

**Edited:**
Examples as suggested by Joseph Wright♦:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
...και η συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (σv.π.π.)
\end{document}
```

produces:

> ...και η συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (σ.π.π.)

while

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
...και η συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (σ.π.π.)
\end{document}
```

produces:

> ...και η συνάρτηση πυκνότητας πιθανότητας (ς.π.π.)

Comment: I replaced `iso-8859-7` (doesn't work properly with my editor) with `utf8`. Then, σ was always typeset as σ, regardless of a following v (wich was never printed), a following dot or a following space.

Comment: Now that's interesting @Tiuri! I'm afraid I have so many documents in iso-8859-7 that switching is not an options. Anyway, the problem is solved, but I would like to find out why this happens.

Comment: Can you show a log-file?

Comment: My guess there is that this is actually a _feature_ of one of the two packages here, to make typesetting Greek in LaTeX easier. Since v is not needed to represent one of the letters of the Greek alphabet, it seems to be used here as a masking sign to just achieve this: typeset sigma as the standard sigma even if not followed by another letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can reproduce the output with this document which doesn't need inputenc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\char115  \char115. \char115v. \char115. vvvvvvvvvvvvv

\end{document}
```

[image]

It works with ligatures. The grmn1095.tfm contains eg.

```
  (LABEL C s)
   (LIG/ O 56 C c)
```

which means that the sigma (C s) together with a period (O 56) is replaced by c+period.

The v (which doesn't print anything) interrupts the ligatures.

With utf8-encoding you don't get the ligature, as then the `σ` is defined as `\textsigma`, and `\textsigma` is defined (in `lgrenc.def`) with a boundary:

```
   \DeclareTextCommand{\textsigma}{LGR}{s\noboundary}
```

Comment: When "v" is used, I would expect a warning about a nonexistent character in the log.  Understandable, but likely misleading.

Comment: The same output can be obtained with `ss. sv. s. vvvvvvvvvv`

Comment: @barbarabeeton The character `v` necessarily exists in the font, otherwise there couldn't be ligatures against it. It has a height of 4.304495pt and a width of 0.00027pt.

Comment: @egreg -- Okay, so that position in the font is simply "invisible".  I guess I just don't know what font that might be.  (I understand the principle, having used it, but with an actual character position that "disappeared", in the MR transliteration input for the University of Washington cyrillic.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The TFM file defines ligatures `vX->X` for `X` any uppercase letter or `v`. In other cases, `v` just occupies 0.00027pt (18sp). I guess there are technical reasons for this.